# Default paper size is A4 instead of US letter

Tags: texlive, article, paper-size

Quoted from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_size:

> It will not have been immediately obvious - because it doesn't really cause any serious problems - that the default page size for all standard document classes is US letter.

I created a simple document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

After I compile this into PDF with TeX Live, I always get A4 size output.

```
$ pdflatex foo.tex
$ identify -verbose foo.pdf | grep Print
  Print size: 8.26389x11.6944
```

I can reproduce this on Ubuntu and Mac. Is the Wikibooks wrong in this case? Does the output size default depend on the Tex Live defaults?

Comment: “US Letter” may be the overall default page size. However, depending on how TeXlive was installed on your system, a different system-specific default page size could have been set. Please tell us more about how TeXlive was installed on *your* system.

Comment: You have to change the setting with `tlmgr`, On MacTeX it's easier with TeX Live Utility.

Comment: @Mico `apt-get install texlive` on Ubuntu and `brew install basictex` on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default TeX Live is installed with A4 paper chosen by default.

If your environment requires US Letter paper, just run

```
tlmgr paper letter
```

with the appropriate privileges.

On macOS, you can use TeX Live Utility (provided you installed TeX Live as MacTeX): menu Configure > Change Paper Size…

Comment: Minor clarification on this: TeX Live Utility doesn't require you to have installed MacTeX or BasicTeX using an Apple Installer package, but you'll have to adjust the path to `tlmgr` manually.